# Actions hover in Selenium tests not working in Jenkins

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, mouseover

I have a selenium UI test written in Java that hovers over an element using Actions.

```
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("path to element"));
    Actions hover = new Actions(driver);
    hover.moveToElement(element).perform();
```

This works running it through commandline, but fails when it's runs on a Jenkins windows node. I have read that instead of using Actions, to use JavascriptExecutor. I have been researching how to do that and came up with

```
    String strJavaScript = "var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');"
            + "evObj.initMouseEvent(\"mouseover\", true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);"
            + "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);";
    JavascriptExecutor js =  (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript(strJavaScript, HoverElement);
```

But this doesn't seem to work either. What am I missing?

Comment: Add windows size to your driver setup. For chrome `chromeOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");`